# How can the value of a checkbox be added to my total sum if I check the box or subtracted if I uncheck it?

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a form with different input boxes to calculate and present the correct value for "totalsumma" if I change the value in any box and it works just fine.

Now I need to add at least one checkbox ("ad11") and add the value from it to "totalsumma" if the checkbox is checked by clicking it (but not if I uncheck it).

My problem is that the value of the box is added to "totalsumma" when I load the form even though the checkbox is not checked, and "totalsumma" does not changes if I click the box as well.

```
<....... some input text boxes ......>
<input type="checkbox" name="ad11" id="ad11" value="6000" />    

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
window.onload = function() { calculate() }

    $('#bredd').keyup(calculate);
    $('#djup').keyup(calculate);

    $('#m2pris2').keyup(calculate);
    $('#grundpris2').keyup(calculate);

$('#ad11').on("change", function(){ 
    calculate()
});



});

function calculate(e)
{

var bredd = parseFloat($('#bredd').val().replace(",", "."));
var djup = parseFloat($('#djup').val().replace(",", "."));


     if($('#ad11').is(":checked")){
         //Add the checkbox value
     }
     else


$('#m2').val(bredd * djup);

    $('#grundpris').val($('#grundpris2').val());
    $('#m2pris').val($('#m2pris2').val());

    $('#ytpris')  .  val(   $('#m2').val()   *  $('#m2pris2').val()  );
$('#totalsumma')  .  val(   parseFloat($('#ytpris').val() ) + parseFloat($('#grundpris2') .val()) + parseFloat($('#ad11') .val())  );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind on change event to the checkbox and then check if the checkbox is checked in the calculate function

```
$('#ad11').on("change", function(){ 
    calculate()
});

function calculate(e)
{
    //Calculations
     if($('#ad11').is(":checked")){
         //Add the checkbox value
     }
     else
         //Don't add the checkbox value
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same problem. Maybe I missunderstood where to put the parts in the script. I've changed my code at the top how it looks like right now ... what have I done wrong?

Comment: In the if($('#ad11').is(":checked")) you add all the values to the total sum including the checkbox value, and in the else you add all the values to the total sum except the checkbox value.

Comment: Thank you! It works :)
I maybe need more checkboxes as well. Is it possible to do like 
if($('#ad11' OR '#ad12' OR '#ad13').is(":checked")){...}

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your_checkbox").change(function() {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        var ans = parseFloat($("#totalsumma").html());
        $("#totalsumma").html(ans + val);
    }
    else
    {
        var ans = parseFloat($("#totalsumma").html());
        $("#totalsumma").html(ans - val);
    }
});
```